# What wrong i am doing in Theme.php during theme creation in Shopware configure theme button goes disable?

Tags: php, shopware

I am adding below code in Theme.php and when i am checking in backend Configure Theme button goes disable.

```
<?php
namespace Shopware\Themes\NextTheme;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Shopware\Components\Form as Form;
use Shopware\Components\Theme\ConfigSet;

class Theme extends \Shopware\Components\Theme
{
    protected $extend="Responsive";
    protected $name="NextTheme";
    protected $description="";
    protected $licence="";
    protected $inheritanceConfig=false;

    public function createConfig(Form\Container\TabContainer $container)
    {
       $tab=$this->createTab('workshop_tabs','Workshop Tabs',[]);
       $container->addTab($tab);

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you wnat to do, but you should try extend `\Shopware\Themes\Responsive\Theme` instead of `\Shopware\Components\Theme` and use `parent::createConfig()`, then add your own tab with some elements.

```
<?php
namespace Shopware\Themes\NextTheme;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Shopware\Components\Form as Form;
use Shopware\Components\Theme\ConfigSet;

class Theme extends \Shopware\Components\Theme
{
    protected $extend="Responsive";
    protected $name="NextTheme";
    protected $description="";
    protected $licence="";
    protected $inheritanceConfig=false;

    /**
     * @param Form\Container\TabContainer $container
     */
    public function createConfig(Form\Container\TabContainer $container)
    {
        parent::createConfig($container);

        $tab=$this->createTab('workshop_tabs','Workshop Tabs',[]);
        $container->addTab($tab);
    }
}
```